# Using MVC Controller to pass data into ng-repeat in MVC View (beginner)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, controller

I am trying to basically connect a SQL server DB to my angular application using .NET MVC. I initially built the app on **[Plunker (demo)](http://embed.plnkr.co/uhwXJ456OyRFQbXnz1rS/preview)** and used a factory class for temp data, but now I am trying to implement it in MVC with real db data. My problem is that I am getting confused on Controllers, since MVC has a controller itself along with AngularJS's own controllers and I am not sure how to connect the two.

What I have thus far is the following.

**MVC Controller (condensed)**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
   private MoviesEntities db = new MoviesEntities();
        public ActionResult account()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.name));
        }
}
```

**MVC View**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Entities.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "account";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutTest.cshtml";
}

@Styles.Render("/Content/style.css")
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="AccountController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search.$">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr ng-repeat="actors in Model">
                <td>{{actors.name}}</td>
                <td>{{actors.summoner}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app.js")
```

Now at this point I tried adding a reference to my `app.js` file but no data is shown or displayed, just a table with {{actors.name}} and {{actors.summoner}}. I  have been searching and trying to find some tutorial on this basic implementation but cannot find a thing. If someone could show me what to do and explain why this isn't working that'd be awesome! I think the use of Controllers is just throwing me off, and I am not sure how to turn my `factory` in `app.js` into holding the database table values.

**app.js** (plunker demo of what I am trying to implement onto MVC now -> **[Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/uhwXJ456OyRFQbXnz1rS/preview)**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })

    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })

    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })

    .when('/account', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/account.html',
        controller: 'AccountController'
    })

    .when('/unknown', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/unknown.html',
        controller: 'UnknownController'
    })
      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/unknown'
      });
});


app.factory('userService', function () {
    return {
        users: [{
            name: "John",
            password: "12345",
            email: "johnny@gmail.com",
            phone: "238-491-2138"
        }, {
            name: "Austin",
            password: "intern",
            email: "aanderson@gmail.com",
            phone: "138-490-1251"
        }, {
            name: "Sally",
            password: "noob",
            email: "Sally123@gmail.com",
            phone: "243-421-0738"
        }, {
            name: "Bilbo",
            password: "Baggins",
            email: "oneRing@gmail.com",
            phone: "158-491-2138"
        }, {
            name: "Marco",
            password: "Wafflez",
            email: "waffleLord@gmail.com",
            phone: "935-491-2654"
        }, {
            name: "Sam",
            password: "Adams",
            email: "beeeeeer@gmail.com",
            phone: "743-491-2131"
        }, {
            name: "Willy",
            password: "W0nk4",
            email: "w0nkaz@gmail.com",
            phone: "682-491-2983"
        }]

    };
});

app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $location, userService, $timeout) {
    $scope.credentials = {
        username: "",
        password: ""
    };
    $scope.credentialsR = {
        username: "",
        password: ""
    };

    $scope.login = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < userService.users.length; i++) {
            if (userService.users[i].name.toLowerCase() === $scope.credentials.username.toLowerCase()) {
                if (userService.users[i].password === $scope.credentials.password) {
                    $scope.messageLogin = "Success!";
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $location.path("/home");
                        }, 500)
                        $scope.messageLogin = "Redirecting...";
                    }, 500)
                } else {
                    $scope.messageLogin = "Incorrect login details";
                }

                return;
            }
        }

        $scope.messageLogin = "Username does not exist";
    };

    $scope.checkName = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < userService.users.length; i++) {
            if (userService.users[i].name.toLowerCase() === $scope.credentialsR.username.toLowerCase()) {
                $scope.messageRegister = "Taken";
                return;
            }
        }

        $scope.messageRegister = "Available";
    };
});

app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Home";
});

app.controller('AccountController', function ($scope, userService, $resource) {
    var Users = $resource('/Test/')
    $scope.userList = userService.users;
});

app.controller('UnknownController', function ($scope) {

});
```

I also used NuGet to install AngularJS, so I believe referencing `angular.js` at the bottom should be fine as well.

Started building this layout from **[ngRepeat and Filtering Data](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-ngrepeat-and-filtering-data)**

**Current Error(s)**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource
    at http://localhost:56087/Scripts/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:56087/Scripts/angular.js:3776:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:56087/Scripts/angular.js:3904:39)
    at http://localhost:56087/Scripts/angular.js:3781:45
    at getService (http://localhost:56087/Scripts/angular.js:3904:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:56087/Scripts/angular.js:3931:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:56087/Scripts/angular.js:3951:23)
    at http://localhost:56087/Scripts/angular.js:7244:28
    at http://localhost:56087/Scripts/angular.js:6635:34
    at forEach (http://localhost:56087/Scripts/angular.js:332:20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `angular-route.min.js` or `angular-route.js` after `angular.js`. If you do not have it on your `Scripts` folder, check `NuGet`.

Try also using `angular-resource.js` **[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource)**

> The ngResource module provides interaction support with RESTful services via the $resource service.

**`View`**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-route.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-resource.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app.js")
```

You also need to fix your module declaration to include ngResource:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute','ngResource']);
```

When i am trying to get data to use in Angular, i have a WEB API service as the data provider. Then i do a get call in my angular controller.

For instance, in your case instead of returning data in your ActionResult, have a webapi controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    using(MoviesEntities db = new MoviesEntities())
    {
        var result = db.Users.OrderBy(x => x.name).Select(x=>new{x.name,x.summoner}).ToList();
        HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage();
        msg.Content = new ObjectContent<object>(result, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());



        msg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Then in your Angular Controller call that service and fill your `$scope`:

```
app.controller('AccountController', function ($scope, userService, $resource, $http) {
    $scope.getUsers = function () {
        $http({
            url: '/api/APITest',
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.userList = angular.copy(result.data);
        })
    }
    getUsers();
});
```

Your `View` also needs some change. Use `userList` instead of `Model`. Probably you would like to rename `actors` to `actor` or even `user` as it would make more sence:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="actors in userList">
        <td>{{actors.name}}</td>
        <td>{{actors.summoner}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

A piece of advise: Create an `_AngularLayout` and add the script declaration there. Then use this for your angular enabled views. That way you do not have to define them in each of your views.

Comment: ah yes yes, but it still does not work haha. I think I need to do something with my Controllers..

Comment: Then try `F12` on your browser and see what the error is.

Comment: updated thread for cleaner view. `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:`
`Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:`
`Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name...<omitted>...2)`

Comment: You also need : `angular-resource.js` ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59276/discussion-between-giannis-paraskevopoulos-and-austin).

Comment: Got a couple of Q's in chat if you're still free. Conceptual stuff about my `app.js`.